# Which matrix operation should I use.

Tags: matrices, matlab

The title is quite vague, but I don't see how to phrase it.

I'm new to MatLab and have very little experience with matrix calculation.

Suppose a matrix "a" :

```
a =

     2     5
     6    12
    13    17
```

It represent some intervals of values.

Then a matrix "b" that represent wider intervals :

```
b =

     1     8
     9    20
```

I need to compare these two matrix so the result will have the same number of rows than `a` and as many columns as there are rows in `b`. In that particular case the result should be :

```
result =

     4     0
     3     4
     0     5
```

explanation : the first row of result is `[4, 0]` because the first row of `a` have 2 4 values included in the interval of the first rows of `b` and 0 in the second. 2, 3, 4 and 5 (from `a`) all falls between 1 and 8 (from `b`).

The second row is `[3, 4]` because 6, 7 and 8 fall between 1 and 8 (3 numbers in the first intervals of `b`) while 9, 10, 11 and 12 fall between 9 and 20 (4 numbers in the second interval of `b`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intervals are $[p,q]$ and $[r,s]$, then the size of the intersection is $\max(0,1 + \min(q,s) - \max(p,r))$. So the following code should work:

```
m = size(a,1);
n = size(b,1);
lower = max( repmat(a(:,1),1,n), repmat(b(:,1),1,m).' );
upper = min( repmat(a(:,2),1,n), repmat(b(:,2),1,m).' );
c = max( 0, 1 + upper - lower );
```

Comment: I don't _really_ understand, but that seems to work just fine. Awesome.
Would be nice if you could explain further.